# Why is this answer considered as a poor answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, review-audits, late-answers

Would you kindly tell me why is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22103805) considered as a poor quality answer. I'm pretty sure the code-only answers are considered acceptable, so why isn't this one not acceptable?

Comment: @CodyGray in this link: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/short-answers-and-code-only-answers

"Do not flag code-only answers which are obviously based on and contain obvious improvements to the original code"

Comment: *"Flag code-only answers which bear little or no relation to the original code"* seems to bear more resemblance to this case. Do you see `InkWell` anywhere in the original code? It isn't at all obvious what the code dump in the answer has to do with the original question. It certainly isn't a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Also... That's a different site... Code Review has a much more constrained purpose

Comment: Also, you're cherry-picking a tiny little bit of text out that link and using it to make your case.  How about this bit of text instead?  *"A code-only answer would be tantamount to committing code to a repository without a log message. Would you rewrite your colleague's code without stating a reason? I don't think that that would be acceptable in a professional context... Unless the code contains sufficient justification of the changes embedded in the comments, I don't think that code-only answers should be allowed."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, you're right. When I saw that part of the answer, I just marked that answer as "No Action Needed".

Comment: Do note that the Late Answers queue is different from the Low Quality Posts queue. While code-only answers that might be an *attempt* to solve the problem shouldn't be deleted from LQP (might've been what you were thinking of), Late Answers serves a different purpose; comment/edit/vote to give the new poster feedback when possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rule of thumb: "No Action Needed" is almost always the wrong choice.

Those blank lines are just there to let the first line sink in a bit, because... Yeah, that's not exactly obvious from the UI, eh?

But... "No Action Needed" is still almost always the wrong choice.

Unless you understand the answer - like, you're familiar with the topic, you know the problem being described, and can recognize that the answer not only solves it but explains the solution in a way that's nearly *perfect* - it's very unlikely that you can say with confidence that *no action* is needed. If you're unsure, the button you want to press is **Skip**.

For everything else, there's almost certainly *some* action that you can take. For example, a downvote. Or an upvote. Or an edit. Or a flag. Or a comment that reads, "Hey friend, would you perhaps like to explain how this code solves the asker's problem? It'd help, a lot!"

Or, some combination of those actions.