# Why is this answer considered "very poor quality"?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

In reviewing first posts, I failed an audit which suggests that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/29332876) is of very low quality (I marked it as no action needed). I feel that, while it is not necessarily a great answer, it does attempt to answer the question. There is one comment that suggests that it is a link-only answer (which it isn't really). Shouldn't the quality of the answer in this case be determined by up/down votes rather than review?

[image: Image of audit answer]

Comment: Relevant: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/11682469)

Comment: I have to agree that while it's not a very good answer, it doesn't look like a link-only NAA. Although I'm confused by your last sentence. Judging the answer by its votes surely approves that it ***is*** in fact low quality...

Comment: @JeanneDark thank you.  I recently had a VLQ flag declined with the suggestion that VLQ should be reserved for posts that are embarrassingly bad--I would suggest that this answer is not that.

Comment: @Tomerikoo thank you. What I meant by the last sentence is that readers of the answer in the original question thread should downvote the answer (rather than having flagged in the review queue).

Comment: It looks incorrect to me that this answer was automatically deleted from review.

Comment: It is surely borderline enough to at least not be an audit...

Comment: From the timeline this has been presented as an audit three times and every time people have selected "no action needed"

Comment: @MartinSmith this is not automatically deleted some users looked at it an decided to delete it

Comment: The history says "post deleted from review" and "Recommend Deletion × 4, Looks OK × 2" so I assume automatic when some threshold is reached

Comment: For further reading: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/11682469), [How does the LQPRQ work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318744/11682469). The, in my opinion, best suggestion is that mods should review posts before they become audits, but who knows if this will ever happen.

Comment: [Castles and not "an apple"s](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/299295). The answer tell about X and then out of sudden suggest Y without any explanation how Y would help. I agree, kind of tricky, but that's why you have to "Skip".

Comment: It is not that bad that this answer got deleted. The text is unrelated to the problem, the link target is a web-crawler page and is also talking about unrelated stuff. The only useful thing their are the interceptor examples. I can see why someone would argue "link only", because the only useful part is behind that link. I guess the best option here would be to undelete it, to clear the "low quality" marker and re-delete it if three 20k users want to.

Comment: Just because this isn't NAA doesn't mean that "No action needed" was the correct choice - remember that this is the First Posts queue, not the Low Quality Posts queue. In First Posts, if an answer isn't *great* but doesn't obviously deserve a downvote, you should absolutely comment to give OP an idea of how to improve it. This audit wasn't great, but IMO it wasn't poor either, since the answer *is* noticeably somewhat lacking. "No action needed" is rarely the optimal choice in FP and LA.

Comment: As [Shog9 said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379799/11682469): "Rule of thumb: "No Action Needed" is almost always the wrong choice."

Comment: @Tom agreed, but unfortunately a whole bunch of not very informative fluff in front of a link (which to make matters worse is not helpful at all) basically disqualifies an answer as being link only.

Comment: I think the confluence of the links provided in the comments suggests that the right course of action is not to select "No Action Needed" when electing to allow the original thread readers to decide the quality of an answer. It seems that in cases like this, skip seems to be the best choice.

Comment: Funny, I was the one who posted the comment. I was presented this answer in the Low Quality Posts queue. My rationale for choosing "link-only" is that the answer failed to include the relevant parts of the link in the answer, and the rest of the answer does not immediately seem related to the question (it is, but it is not obvious to someone unfamiliar with the API). Seeing as Low Quality Posts does not have an option "needs considerable rewrite", and at least half the question matches the criteria for "link-only answer", I selected that option.

Comment: That said, for future reviews I will just skip the tricky cases

Comment: **Your decision on that review was correct.** One could, perhaps, argue that the answer could have been improved by submitting an edit, but no other course of action would have been appropriate. That definitely isn't a very poor quality answer, and it definitely didn't need to be deleted. In fact, that's a *great* review audit, it's just... the system has it backwards. Anyone who is voting to delete that is reviewing incorrectly. Either way, thanks for reporting the bad audit; Machavity has addressed the issue now. You weren't the first person to be tripped up by this bug.

Comment: @CodyGray **your evaluation of this review is incorrect**, sorry. I just happen to be familiar with question topic and if I stumbled over this answer organically, I would at the very least comment asking author to clarify how it relates to the question asked. While we're at it, your change of duplicate targets here doesn't feel right either

Comment: No, @gnat. If you're bringing subject-matter expertise into it, then you're doing things wrong. Anyone who voted to delete this answer has been suspended from review, and would be in future cases. If you want to downvote and vote to delete it outside of the review queues using 20k+ "trusted user" privileges, that's a whole different kettle of fish. But we don't delete answers through review because you don't think they're technically accurate or appropriate.

Comment: @CodyGray this is first posts review, not LQ, and bringing subject matter is totally appropriate. Re-read the FAQ guidance on FP/LA reviews if you have forgotten, it specifically says "not simply hit No Action Needed just because it passes a couple of the smell tests". As for deletion, you bringing it here looks irrelevant because as I wrote the reasonable review action (other than Skip) would be comment, I wrote nothing about deletion

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This wasn't a good review overall, which [has been a longstanding problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/2370483). I can only assume people reviewed it as link-only, which it is not. It might not be a **good** answer, but that's what downvotes are for. It suggests a course of action for the asker to take. Granted, it would have been more useful had there been some quote from the link, but that's not a good reason to delete it.

I have undeleted the answer. If it's not useful, please downvote and comment.